# iphone posting link to facebook wall - image

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a link to my fb account via fbgraph API. The thing is that when I post the link to fb, an icon is appearing on left side of that link i.e, for example if I post www.google.com ,then the google image is appearing in left side of the link.

how to change that default icon to my desired icon ? (or) what is the default image location it is taking from the site.
[image: updated]
Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set in facebook for your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

It is your app icon.

For example mine is a giant wale ;-)

[image]

To add  a picture to your post just add the parameter @"picture" and fillin the url to the picture you want to see.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"myFacebookAppId", @"app_id",
                               @"http://www.homepage.com", @"link",
                               @"http//www.homepage.com/sillypicture.png", @"picture",
                               @"name of the post", @"name",
                               @"caption of my post", @"caption",
                               @"content of my post", @"description",
                               @"my message", @"message",
                               nil];

[[[myAppDelegate sharedDelegate] facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: i think you wrongly understood my question when i am posting a link to facebook via my iphone app in the sense it randomly taking image from site which i posted check the below attached image it appeared when i am posting google.com link.

Comment: I was confused by the "icon" in the question, I suppose you ment to ask how to add a picture with your link post? I edite the answer in that way.