# Facebook iPhone like iTunes app will load an incorrect image

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-like

In my iPhone application I have a feature that lets users share my application on their facebook accounts, I use the following code to archive this:

```
faceBook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"];  
[faceBook authorize:nil delegate:self];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [@"iTunes AppStore URL",  @"link",
                               nil];
[faceBook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

I have several iPhone applications already available on the iTunes AppStore, and when I use the above function Facebook use `SSO` and shows a view to the user to Post, but the large image on the left side is incorrect, instead of the correct logo I get the logo of the first Application I posted on the AppStore.

I have setup the Facebook App correctly with the icon and the logo. this question is related to the following [iphone posting link to facebook wall - image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868519/iphone-posting-link-to-facebook-wall-image)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what I would say is that the Facebook app often shows the wrong picture associated with friends. Maybe you're doing nothing wrong and it's the API that's broken?